# Is there a shorthand for the symbols ../ for n higher directories in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, path

For example.  If I have some dir, I need to reference a relative path to current dir 5 folders above I can write.

```
..\..\..\..\..\someDir
```

Is there a way to shorten this even further, like using a numeric or another shorthand using built-in path expansion in windows?

For context using Windows 10

Comment: Not in Win NT the current Windows. Win 9x supported Novell's `\.......\ ` to go up 5 levels.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such shortcut, but there is an up-arrow icon
for navigating to the parent folder, situated left from the
path field.

It's also possible to navigate to the parent folder by using the
shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up-arrow</kbd>.

If clicking 5 times on the icon or pressing 5 time this shortcut
is too much work, you may create such a shortcut yourself,
using the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>F12</kbd>
to sending 5 times the above shortcut:

```
F12::Send, !{Up 5}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)